# Unable to debug the Controller for Error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, error-handling, exception

Why is that I can't debug the controller that handles the error page. What I've added is to print the exception message. I put breakpoints on that part.

It's successfully displayed the error.jsp. But the breakpoints were not recognized.

Here are my codes.

**web.xml**

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.htm</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/500.htm</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <location>/500.htm</location>
    </error-page>
```

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping("/500.htm")
    public ModelAndView errorFound(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Exception ex) throws ServletException {
        logger.error("ERROR FOUND --> ", ex);
        return new ModelAndView("/common/error");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/404.htm")
    public ModelAndView pageNotFound(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Exception ex) throws ServletException {
        logger.error("PAGE NOT FOUND --> ", ex);
        return new ModelAndView("/common/error");
    }
```

I'm using Eclipse Neon.

Do you think the problem is with my IDE?

**UPDATES:**

**1.** Even if I deleted the above controller functions, still the error message was directed to error.jsp

**2.** codes: dispatcherservlet.xml

```
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

**3.** Im using Java 7, Apache 7, Spring 3.1.0

Comment: Did you mapped any path in your controller except `"/404.htm"` or `"/500.htm"`

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna only the controller above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you put your jsp under `/WEB-INF/jsp/` folder. Putting error code against jsp in `web.xml` directly show your error page. No need to redirect to any controller. So you do not include any controller mapped url to show the page.

In this case if your jsp reside in `/WEB-INF/jsp/` then you can configure your `web.xml` in such that

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

If you want to show your exception in page then you need to configure your `Exception.class` into generic one. Create a class using `@ControllerAdvice` and `@EnableWebMvc`.
What is ControllerAdvice annotation ?
From [spring docs](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes):

> A controller advice allows you to use exactly the same exception handling techniques but apply them across the whole application, not just to an individual controller. You can think of them as an annotation driven interceptor.

Your Custom Exception handler class somehow look like

```
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class CustomExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleException(Exception exception){
        ModelAndView andView = new ModelAndView();
        andView.addObject("exception",exception);
        andView.setViewName("/common/error");
        return andView;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.. I will try this one.. but for <location> , do I really need to include the **/WEB-INF/jsp** even though I already declared it in my dispatcherservlet.xml (see my updates on this post)? .. thank you

Comment: Though you declare,you should use the path `/WEB-INF/jsp`